# Bluetooth dongle not working

Tags: usb, bluetooth, dongle

I had a BT dongle that worked on my PC with Xubuntu 14.04. Now I have Xubuntu 16.04 and it doesn't work any more. I use this dongle only 5 or 6 times a year so I'm not 100% sure if it worked on 16.04 or not.
No matter which usb port the dongle is connected to: the problem is the same.
The dongle works on a windows 7 PC
Some stuff below so you can understand my problem.

**uname -a**

```
Linux R2D2 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**sudo service bluetooth status**

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since sam. 2016-07-16 08:25:45 CEST; 3h 3min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 897 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─897 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

juil. 16 08:25:45 R2D2 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
juil. 16 08:25:45 R2D2 bluetoothd[897]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
juil. 16 08:25:45 R2D2 bluetoothd[897]: Starting SDP server
juil. 16 08:25:45 R2D2 bluetoothd[897]: Bluetooth management interface 1.10 initialized
juil. 16 08:25:45 R2D2 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
```

**sudo hciconfig -a**

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 11:11:11:11:11:11  ACL MTU: 672:3  SCO MTU: 48:1
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:2225 acl:0 sco:0 events:75 errors:0
    TX bytes:315 acl:0 sco:0 commands:75 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0x3e 0x85 0x38 0x18 0x18 0x00 0x00
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

**sudo hciconfig hci0 up**

```
Can't init device hci0: Operation not supported (95)
```

**sudo hcitool scan**

```
Device is not available: No such device
```

**sudo hcitool inq**

```
Inquiring ...
Inquiry failed.: No such device
```

**sudo hciconfig hci0 reset**

```
Can't init device hci0: Operation not supported (95)
```

**sudo rfkill list**

```
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

**sudo lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0e5e:6622 Conwise Technology Co., Ltd. CW6622
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1a7c:0191 Evoluent VerticalMouse 4
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My dongle is: Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0e5e:6622 Conwise Technology Co., Ltd. CW6622

**sudo lsmod | grep btusb**

```
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             520192  12 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,btintel
```

**sudo dmesg | tail**

```
[ 5049.928066] usb 2-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 5050.022000] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=0e5e, idProduct=6622
[ 5050.022006] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

**sudo tail /var/log/syslog**

```
Jul 16 09:49:48 R2D2 kernel: [ 5049.928066] usb 2-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
Jul 16 09:49:48 R2D2 kernel: [ 5050.022000] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=0e5e, idProduct=6622
Jul 16 09:49:48 R2D2 kernel: [ 5050.022006] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Jul 16 09:49:48 R2D2 systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Jul 16 09:49:48 R2D2 systemd-udevd[5159]: Process '/bin/hciconfig hci0 up' failed with exit code 1.
Jul 16 09:49:48 R2D2 systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Jul 16 09:49:48 R2D2 systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
```

What could the problem be?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Not even a little hint?

Comment: Having the same issue. Any hints?